# Javascript How to scale Array, prevent errors from undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, meteor

I am currently creating a quiz app in meteor. One of the key variables Im using is called currentQuestions which keeps track of the questionnumber of each quiz the user has taken. It is currently an array which updates (in a Meteor session) everytime the user clicks the next or back button on a particular quiz. for example:

```
   currentQuestion = Session.get('currentQuestion') || [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

This works fine for a small amount of quizzes. What would you suggest however when I want to have a large amount of quizzes? Currently when I create more quizzes than I have previously defined in the currenQuestion Array the app crashes.

Possible solution I have thought of

1. (Ugly solutions) Create a for loop that fills up the currentQuestion array with a large amount of zero's at startup.
2. Insert a object into the mongoDB database that contains the currentquestion with the id of the quiz that's taken (so getting rid of the array entirely)

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 2 is definitely the right one:

If you don't need to keep track of scores between sessions, you can just use a client-side-only database and store objects as you suggest and it will be only a couple of lines of new code for a much more flexible outcome.

This would then be very easy to convert into a persistent store as well: either add sign-in with Meteor's accounts package, add the current `userId` to each quiz object, and then only publish the quiz objects with the same `userId` as the logged-in user.  Alternatively, you could even use the amplify package to store results between sessions in a given browser if you wanted to avoid user login entirely (you'd have to pull existing results out again on startup, but this is very easy).

The result would have all the reactivity of a Session variable built in, and would avoid the need to populate an array with an arbitrary and changing number of zeros - just check whether the a document with the given quiz Id is in the collection or not, and if not then create it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! How do you suggest I go about that? I now have a UserData collection which features the array. How would I convert that to a quiz object with a user id? I;m guessing you have a quiz object within UserData that contains each quiz id and the relevant currentquestion on it. I',m a bit lost though as how to exactly create such an extra layer within my mongodb

Comment: It's a bit difficult to describe it without seeing the code.  However, rather than have objects within your `UserData` documents, I would have a totally separate `QuizData` collection, which has documents that contain `userId`, `quizId` and `score` (or whatever it is that's being stored in the array at present).  Then for a logged-in user, you can just filter (i.e. `find`) the documents by `userId` on the server side and return these through `Meteor.publish` so that the logged-in user only ever sees their own scores even though they're all being held in the same collection.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to get rid of the array entirely. If you are going to keep track between sessions then you'll need to go with something like mongoDB. You could created something like a progress or completion model which can hold info about the quizzes they have taken and progress for each. Once you have that stores those by some userId related key.

Your dirty solution is not the worst since you'll know at start how many quizzes you'll have and can allocate the array then.